# If statement returning wrong value

Tags: python

```
import time
print("Welcome My Fellow Friend")
print("You have £5000")
rs = input("Would you like to buy a Ford Focus RS?")
if rs ==  "yes":
  print("You Have Bought The Ford Focus RS BALANCE = £0.00")
elif rs == "no":
  print("ok")
```

> OK so the problem is when i enter yes it will return You Have Bought The Ford Focus RS BALANCE = £0.00 but when i put no it returns the same thing!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use else? And it looks fine to me

Comment: This code works fine on my computer.

Comment: What is that `rpg` tag anyway? Are you sure your question is completed?

Comment: how are you running this?

Comment: Pressing F5 or running the Module

Comment: have you saved it before running it?

Comment: Edit your answer and write more details: which Ide, Which Version, Win/Mac/Linux, how are you calling your python file.

Comment: as it stands your code should work fine so either we are missing some code or you are not running the correct code. There is no way entering `no` makes the first if statement True